# SQS URL signing:: Do we really need to sign every time we make Query Requests?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am using this scratchpad to play around with SQS - http://aws.amazon.com/code/developertools/1254 and I found that every time I make a request like send a message to my queue I need to sign it then execute.. Is it really like that?

I thought you just need to calculate your signature then reuse that signature every time you send your request..

Comment: I am now using  aws android sdk - http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforandroid/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to sign each request.  Without signing every request, if an attacker were able to get a hold of one of your requests, then they would have your signature and then be able to  send, receive and delete messages in your queue.  This is why the message body and the expires time are part of the string to sign.

Comment: Thank you so much but I changed my approach and use android SDK - http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforandroid/